# SwiftUI - how to make TextField not editable (at all) while preserving touch for scrolling

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I need to use a TextField (rather than Text) because of the way it scrolls instead of truncating text over the line limit. But I cannot figure out how to completely disable editing without losing scrolling. .disabled(true) disables both. I have made the text to be displayed a constant, but the user is still able to tap on the field and type one character, which will disappear when they tap anywhere on the screen. It's non-destructive, but sloppy.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `Text` inside `ScrollView`, and with the `lineLimit` set to `nil`:

```
ScrollView { // <-- add scroll around Text
    Text(longText)
        .lineLimit(nil) // <-- tell Text to use as many lines as it needs (so no truncating)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // <-- tell Text to take the entire space available for ScrollView
} 
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // <-- if needed, tell ScrollView to use the full size of its parent too
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but I do need to be able to configure the scroll view to scroll if the contents of the Text exceed a max number of lines.  TextField makes this easy;  I'm not quite sure how to do it with ScrollView.  Any suggestions?

Comment: do you mean you want to hide ScrollView unless Text exceeds certain number of lines?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.